# Keep two versions of AWS Lambdas running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, version, serverless-framework

Simple explanation of my current infrastructure: I am using AWS Lambdas (running python code there), which are deployed via the Gitlab CI using serverless framework.

Explanation of situation: I currently have an AWS Lambda which uses a specific library version (for now say version 1.x.x). At some point in time, this Lambda will start using a new version of the this library (say 2.x.x), but I want both of these lambdas to be still deployed and available to handle requests.

If at some other point in time the version 3.x.x of the library comes, I want to keep the lambda using version 3.x.x and 2.x.x running (basically the current version and current version - 1 lambdas). Lets call them Lambda_NEW and Lambda_OLD.

AWS lambdas have the concepts of versions and aliases which could be used, but unfortunately they are not supported by serverless directly. 
Note: serverless supports multiple versions (which cannot be named) and there is a plugin called serverless-aws-aliases which can set aliases for you, but that one refer to the actual AWS Lambda versions (see https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-aws-alias/issues/148).

Do you have any idea on how to tackle it?

My only valid thought so far is to keep two branches (NEW and OLD) which will use two different versions of the library, and each branch will have its different deploy CI. This is very counter intuitive though, since I don't know how to maintain develop and master branches. Also, when to deploy to which stage etc.

Also I somehow want both Lambda_NEW and Lambda_OLD to be deployed on the same time (e.g. when switching to library 5.x.x, I want version 5.x.x to be in the NEW and version 4.x.x in the old)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure from your post, but I gather that you want a way to handle canary deployments, so that you could easily roll back changes? If that's not the case, could you edit your question and provide a bit more clarity?

If that's the case, I'd recommend following [this guide](https://serverless.com/blog/manage-canary-deployments-lambda-functions-serverless-framework/) and using the [canary-deployments](https://github.com/davidgf/serverless-plugin-canary-deployments) plugin, which will automatically create aliases for new versions, and allows you to define how traffic is shifted between deployed versions.

Comment: The question was broad, yes. Solved it using serverless-aws-aliases plugins. See:  https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-aws-alias/issues/148.

I was basically having miss-configured serverless file

Comment: @ilirosmanaj can you pls post answer as well, I am in similar situation and possibly your solution will provide helpful insight

Comment: @mbaxi I am not sure how to post it, rather I will give an explanation on how it worked for me. 

Lambdas are allowed to have multiple versions and for these versions you are allowed to create aliases, such that you can invoke them by different suffixes in lambda name. Every time I want to create a new version, I update the aliases using the aws cli tool.